# Jump to the middle of a Doubly Linked List really fast

Tags: java, optimization, linked-list

is there any way of jumping to the middle element of a Doubly Linked List really fast instead of doing

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numOfElements/2; i++){
element = element.next;
}
```

this needs so much time in my code, if i would optimize it, it would be really cool :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point of a linked (or doubly-linked) list is that random access is slow (`O(n)`).

You need to use a different kind of list, such as a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of a linked list is that this cannot be done. However, there exist other data structures which (indirectly) allow this operation. One such data structure is the [**skip list**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) whose name comes from the fact that it can do precisely that: skip items.

This data structure is not directly applicable in your case since skip lists implement dictionaries, not allow direct access to indexed items. However, the general structure can be adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will make a lot of sense to do it depends on the reason why you need a doubly linked list.  Ideally, you could just opt to not use it. But if this is not possibly you could back it with another type of data structure such as a hashmap with an integer as a key.  Then you could so something like:

```
element.get(numOfElements/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "jump to the middle", do you mean literally the exact middle element every time? Or simply "somewhere other than the beginning or end but the exact place will vary"?

If you mean the exact middle, you could maintain a pointer to the middle of the list along with the usual start and end pointers. Every time an entry is added to or deleted from the list, there would be the possibility that this pointer would have to move. Note that it would take two inserts on either side to move it one position, and one insert below and one above would cancel out. So you'd have to keep a "half counter". When an item is inserted below, subtract one from the half counter. When an item is inserted above, add one. If the half counter is now -2, move the middle pointer down one slot and reset the half counter to 0. If the half counter is now +2, move the middle pointer up one slot and reset the half counter. I did this once years ago. I forget why.

If you don't mean the exact middle, then I think the answer is "it can't be done". You could, I suppose, maintain a number of pointers to various points in the list. Like having a dictionary with tabs for the first A, the first B, etc.

Or I suppose that if you know that you frequently need to get "very near the middle", you could maintain a middle pointer as I describe above and then search from there.

Whether any of this helps with the problem you're really trying to solve, I can't say without more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a middle pointer but that would need to be adjusted each time you update the list, if you only need a approximation that is sufficient

or keep 2 separate lists and each time you access the middle you adjust them until they are of equal length (keep length as a separate var for each)

```
public class DoubledLickedList{
    private Node fhead,ftail,shead,stail;
    private AtomicInteger fsize,sSize;

    public Class Node{
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
        public Node getNext(){
            if(next==null && next==ftail)return shead;
            return next;
        }

        public Node getPrev(){
            if(prev==null && prev==shead)return ftail;
            return prev;
        }
    }

    public Node getMiddle(){
        adjustToMiddle();
        return ftail;
    }

    private void adjustToMiddle(){
        while(fsize.get()>sSize.get()+1){
            //pop first and push it to the second
            fsize.incrementAndGet();
            sSize.decrementAndGet();
        }
        while(sSize.get()>fsize.get()+1){
            //pop second and push it to the first
            sSize.incrementAndGet();
            fsize.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't need a list at all, you may be able use an [Array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), or a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

All have much faster random access.